# Deserialize an object with an IEnumerable using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

Consider the following json and models:

```
{
    "Reference": "Bay House 22",
    "Appliances": [
        {
            "Reference": "Kitchen Appliance 1",
            "ApplianceType": "0",
            "NumberOfSlots": 4
        },
        {
            "Reference": "Kitchen Appliance 2",
            "ApplianceType": "1",
            "Capacity": 1500
        }
    ]
}

public class HouseModel
{
    public String Reference { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ApplianceModelConverter))]
    public IEnumerable<IApplianceModel> Appliances { get; set; }
}

public interface IApplianceModel
{
    String Reference { get; set; }
    ApplianceType ApplianceType { get; set; } // this is an enum
}

public class ToasterModel : IApplianceModel
{
    public String Reference { get; set; }
    public ApplianceType ApplianceType { get; set; }

    public Int32 NumberOfSlots { get; set; }
}

public class KettleModel : IApplianceModel
{
    public String Reference { get; set; }
    public ApplianceType ApplianceType { get; set; }

    public Int32 Capacity { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize an IEnumerable which could be a `Toaster` or a `Kettle`, using a custom json converter. The idea here is that I can return a concrete type once I know what the ApplianceType is, by looking at the json. I've been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base/8031283#8031283) stackoverflow post to try and get this to work, but without success.

Here is the converter code:

```
public abstract class JsonCreationConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    protected abstract T Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject);

    public override Boolean CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override Boolean CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override Object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Load JObject from stream
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        // Create target object based on JObject
        T target = Create(objectType, jObject);

        // Populate the object properties
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

        return target;
    }
}

public class ApplianceModelConverter: JsonCreationConverter<IApplianceModel>
{
    protected override IApplianceModel Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
    {
        if (jObject["applianceType "] == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Missing ApplianceType");
        }

        ApplianceType applianceType = jObject.Value<ApplianceType>();

        switch (applianceType )
        {
            case ApplianceType.Kettle:
                return new KettleModel();
            case ApplianceType.Toaster: 
                return new ToasterModel();
            default:
                throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("ApplianceType not supported");
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I get an exception thrown when this line is executed: `JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);` in the `JsonCreationConverter`

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error reading JObject from
>   JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path
>   'Appliances'

I guess that it's getting to the IEnumerable and just failing, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray` => you are trying to read an array as if it was an object

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. I guess it's because I have the attribute on IEnumerable property rather than the HouseModel

Comment: But why don't you do `JArray data = JArray.Load(reader);`?

Comment: Because the Create is abstract and requires JObject, see `ApplianceModelConverter` this is an override from `JsonCreationConverter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment this line of code

```
    public class HouseModel
{
    public String Reference { get; set; }
    //[JsonConverter(typeof(ApplianceModelConverter))] //=> You don't need this
    public IEnumerable<IApplianceModel> Appliances { get; set; }
}
```

Also Change the Create method to this

```
 protected override IApplianceModel Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
    {
        if (jObject["ApplianceType"] == null) //case sensitive
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Missing ApplianceType");
        }

        //ApplianceType applianceType = jObject.Value<ApplianceType>(); //this might throw invalid cast exception
        ApplianceType applianceType = jObject["ApplianceType"].ToObject<ApplianceType>();


        switch (applianceType)
        {
            case ApplianceType.Kettle:
                return new KettleModel();
            case ApplianceType.Toaster:
                return new ToasterModel();
            default:
                throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("ApplianceType not supported");
        }
    }
```

If We are using this method to deserialize

```
string json = "{\"Reference\": \"Bay House 22\",\"Appliances\": [{\"Reference\": \"Kitchen Appliance 1\",\"ApplianceType\": \"0\",\"NumberOfSlots\": 4},{\"Reference\": \"Kitchen Appliance 2\",\"ApplianceType\": \"1\",\"Capacity\": 1500}]}";

HouseModel houseModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HouseModel>(json, new ApplianceModelConverter());
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I don't think you've understood the question, you're saying to remove the converter and then saying to change the converter. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: string json = "{\"Reference\": \"Bay House 22\",\"Appliances\": [{\"Reference\": \"Kitchen Appliance 1\",\"ApplianceType\": \"0\",\"NumberOfSlots\": 4},{\"Reference\": \"Kitchen Appliance 2\",\"ApplianceType\": \"1\",\"Capacity\": 1500}]}";
                HouseModel houseModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HouseModel>(json, new ApplianceModelConverter()); assuming this is how you are converting what I mentioned above should work

Comment: Yes! My apologies, it seems I didn't understand your answer. Not the other way around. TY